# How can I build a dynamic hedging when jumps occur with python?

Tags: quantitative-finance, computational-finance

I want to build a dynamic hedging strategy when jumps occur. In litterature we have to include another option to reduce the impacts due to the jumps, which is another source of risk.

I tried to find a code, or similar one, written in python, but I haven't found nothing about dynamic hedging when jumps occur.

Thanks in advance